# Need to use jsonlite to handle ndjson message list using stream_in() and stream_out()

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have an ndjson data source.  For a simple example, consider a text file with three lines, each containing a valid json message.  I want to extract 7 variables from the messages and put them in a dataframe.

Please use the following sample data in a text file.  You can paste this data into a text editor and save it as "ndjson_sample.txt"

```
{"ts":"1","ct":"{\"Var1\":6,\"Var2\":6,\"Var3\":-70,\"Var4\":12353,\"Var5\":1,\"Var6\":\"abc\",\"Var7\":\"x\"}"}
{"ts":"2","ct":"{\"Var1\":6,\"Var2\":6,\"Var3\":-68,\"Var4\":4528,\"Var5\":1,\"Var6\":\"def\",\"Var7\":\"y\"}"}
{"ts":"3","ct":"{\"Var1\":6,\"Var2\":6,\"Var3\":-70,\"Var4\":-5409,\"Var5\":1,\"Var6\":\"ghi\",\"Var7\":\"z\"}"}
```

The following three lines of code accomplish what I want to do:

```
file1 <- "ndjson_sample.txt"
json_data1 <- ndjson::stream_in(file1)
raw_df_temp1 <- as.data.frame(ndjson::flatten(json_data1$ct))
```

For reasons I won't get into, I cannot use the `ndjson` package.  I must find a way to use the `jsonlite` package to do the same thing using the `stream_in()` and `stream_out()` functions.  Here's what I tried:

```
con_in1 <- file(file1, open = "rt")
con_out1 <- file(tmp <- tempfile(), open = "wt")
callback_func <- function(df){
  jsonlite::stream_out(df, con_out1, pagesize = 1)
}
jsonlite::stream_in(con_in1, handler = callback_func, pagesize = 1)
close(con_out1)
con_in2 <- file(tmp, open = "rt")
raw_df_temp2 <- jsonlite::stream_in(con_in2)
```

This is not giving me the same data frame as a final output.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I have to change to make `raw_df_temp1` equal `raw_df_temp2`?

I could potentially solve this with a the `fromJSON()` functions operating on each line of the file, but I'd like to find a way to do it with the `stream` functions.  The files I will be dealing with a are quite large and so efficiency will be key.  I need this to be as fast as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to match input with `stream_out(stream_in(...),...)`? You say it *"is not giving me the same data frame"*, what do you get? (please edit your question for that last one)

Comment: I want `raw_df_temp1` to match `raw_df_temp2`.  Perhaps what I'm trying to do with opening and closing the stream connection is not correct.  I'm asking what is the right way to do this using `jsonlite` and the `stream_in` and `stream_out` functions.  Currently, my `raw_dr_temp2` dataframe contains two variables `ts` and `ct`.  Under `ct` you'll find the valid JSON message I want to pull the data from.  I'm looking for the most efficient way to pull this data and populate a dataframe...similar to the way it is done in `ndjson` package.

Answer (score 1):

Currently under `ct` you'll find a *string* that can (subsequently) be fed to `fromJSON` independently, but it will not be parsed as such. Ignoring your `stream_out(stream_in(...),...)` test, here are a couple of ways to read it in:

```
library(jsonlite)
json <- stream_in(file('ds_guy.ndjson'), simplifyDataFrame=FALSE)
# opening file input connection.
#  Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
# closing file input connection.
cbind(
  ts = sapply(json, `[[`, "ts"),
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(json, function(a) fromJSON(a$ct)))
)
#   ts Var1 Var2 Var3  Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7
# 1  1    6    6  -70 12353    1  abc    x
# 2  2    6    6  -68  4528    1  def    y
# 3  3    6    6  -70 -5409    1  ghi    z
```

Calling `fromJSON` on each string might be cumbersome, and with larger data this slow-down is why there is `stream_in`, so if we can capture the `"ct"` component into a stream of its own, then ...

```
writeLines(sapply(json, `[[`, "ct"), 'ds_guy2.ndjson')
```

(There are far-more-efficient ways to do this with non-R tools, including perhaps a simple

```
sed -e 's/.*"ct":"\({.*\}\)"}$/\1/g' -e 's/\\"/"/g' ds_guy.ndjson > ds_guy.ndjson2
```

though this makes a few assumptions about the data that may not be perfectly safe. A better solution would be to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which should "always" correctly-parse proper json, then a quick `sed` to replace escaped quotes:

```
jq '.ct' ds_guy.ndjson | sed -e 's/\\"/"/g' > ds_guy2.ndjson
```

and you can do that with `system(...)` in R if needed.)

From there, under the assumption that each line will contain exactly one row of data.frame data:

```
json2 <- stream_in(file('ds_guy2.ndjson'), simplifyDataFrame=TRUE)
# opening file input connection.
#  Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
# closing file input connection.
cbind(ts=sapply(json, `[[`, "ts"), json2)
#   ts Var1 Var2 Var3  Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7
# 1  1    6    6  -70 12353    1  abc    x
# 2  2    6    6  -68  4528    1  def    y
# 3  3    6    6  -70 -5409    1  ghi    z
```

NB: in the first example, `"ts"` is a `factor`, all others are `character` because that's what `fromJSON` gives. In the second example, all strings are `factor`. This can easily be addressed through judicious use of `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, depending on your needs.

Comment: ds_guy, does this answer your question?